# Azure Environmental Variables how to override web.config value?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, environment-variables

I am doing a dotnet publish on a .net core web api and it generated a **web.config** as below. This works fine for dev as the RayGunKey is the right value, but when I put this on the staging environment it still has the "SOME-KEY-HERE" value! Even though I create the **RayGunKey** (with a different value) under the staging web api's **Configuration** -> **Application Settings**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApi.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="InProcess" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="44392" />
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
          <environmentVariable name="RayGunKey" value="SOME-KEY-HERE" />
          <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Have I not configured the startup file right? How can I get it to pull the staging **RagGunKey** instead of using the one that was created in the publish command?

I am currently using the following code which does seem to pull in the value, from the **web.config**, but as I say I want to pull it from azure application settings(environmental variables)

```
var rayGunKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RayGunKey");
```

I am constantly confused by environmental variables, especial in this case. Calling it Application setting in azure and environmental variables in other places straight away is not intuitive!

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I got to focused on the **launchSettings.json** and added my environmental variables there, where it looks like a nice place to put them! Then Visual studio create the web.config file and populates it with these values defined in the launchSettings.json file. This seems rather broken as now when I do a **dotnet publish** the file will have the last web.config values defined in it. In this case dev details that would be put on staging. Even if I tried to create an environmental variable on staging, supposedly web.config takes precedence so would not see the value.

Instead I use the **appsetting** to configure this, so the only thing that drives the config is the **launchSettings.json** **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** value. When running the app it will look at this environmental variable and get the appropriately named appsettings in this case **appsettings.Staging.json**

As long as I make sure that this is set on each of my environments e.g. to Develeopment, Staging and Production then it will read in the config from the appsettings..json file.See the screenshot of how to do this. I'm not using the Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable anymore too.

[image]

This seems to me like a right balls up and over complication of what was once much simpler